# get external ip from service created via terraform kubernetes manifest

Tags: terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-kubernetes

Hi I am trying to get the external IP of a service. I can see externalIp in the azure console, but the data object does not contain it.

```golang
resource "kubernetes_manifest" "haproxy_controller_svc" {
  manifest = yamldecode(file("${path.root}/k8s/ingress/controller.svc.yaml"))
}

output "ingress_external_ip" {
  value = kubernetes_manifest.haproxy_controller_svc.object.spec.externalIPs[0]
}
```

```sh
$ tf apply
 Error: Attempt to index null value
│ 
│   on ingress.tf line 61, in output "ingress_external_ip":
│   61:   value = kubernetes_manifest.haproxy_controller_svc.object.spec.externalIPs[0]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ kubernetes_manifest.haproxy_controller_svc.object.spec.externalIPs is null
│ 
│ This value is null, so it does not have any indices.
```

Since the ingress already exists and has an IP (from previous tf apply). At this point I don't think its because the Loadbalancer hasn't been provisioned yet in azure. Again I can see it on the dashboard.

If I print the full object. It looks like this.

```sh
ingress_svc_object = {
  "apiVersion" = "v1"
  "kind" = "Service"
  "metadata" = {
    "annotations" = tomap(null) /* of string */
    "clusterName" = tostring(null)
    "creationTimestamp" = tostring(null)
    "deletionGracePeriodSeconds" = tonumber(null)
    "deletionTimestamp" = tostring(null)
    "finalizers" = tolist([
      "service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup",
    ])
    "generateName" = tostring(null)
    "generation" = tonumber(null)
    "labels" = tomap({
      "run" = "haproxy-ingress"
    })
    "managedFields" = tolist(null) /* of object */
    "name" = "haproxy-ingress"
    "namespace" = "ingress"
    "ownerReferences" = tolist(null) /* of object */
    "resourceVersion" = tostring(null)
    "selfLink" = tostring(null)
    "uid" = tostring(null)
  }
  "spec" = {
    "allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts" = tobool(null)
    "clusterIP" = "10.0.147.131"
    "clusterIPs" = tolist([
      "10.0.147.131",
    ])
    "externalIPs" = tolist(null) /* of string */
    "externalName" = tostring(null)
    "externalTrafficPolicy" = "Local"
    "healthCheckNodePort" = 31208
    "internalTrafficPolicy" = tostring(null)
    "ipFamilies" = tolist([
      "IPv4",
    ])
    "ipFamilyPolicy" = "SingleStack"
    "loadBalancerClass" = tostring(null)
    "loadBalancerIP" = tostring(null)
    "loadBalancerSourceRanges" = tolist(null) /* of string */
    "ports" = tolist([
      {
        "appProtocol" = tostring(null)
        "name" = "http"
        "nodePort" = 30281
        "port" = 80
        "protocol" = "TCP"
        "targetPort" = 80
      },
      {
        "appProtocol" = tostring(null)
        "name" = "https"
        "nodePort" = 30705
        "port" = 443
        "protocol" = "TCP"
        "targetPort" = 443
      },
      {
        "appProtocol" = tostring(null)
        "name" = "stat"
        "nodePort" = 30711
        "port" = 1024
        "protocol" = "TCP"
        "targetPort" = 1024
      },
    ])
    "publishNotReadyAddresses" = tobool(null)
    "selector" = tomap({
      "run" = "haproxy-ingress"
    })
    "sessionAffinity" = "None"
    "sessionAffinityConfig" = {
      "clientIP" = {
        "timeoutSeconds" = tonumber(null)
      }
    }
    "topologyKeys" = tolist(null) /* of string */
    "type" = "LoadBalancer"
  }
}
```

Edit:

Status of kubectl describe:

```
$ k get -o yaml service/haproxy-ingress -n ingress
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-08-13T07:28:11Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    run: haproxy-ingress
  name: haproxy-ingress
  namespace: ingress
  resourceVersion: "471823"
  uid: 837281bd-3cb5-4454-93fb-b3d36605444a
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.0.147.131
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.0.147.131
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  healthCheckNodePort: 31208
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 30281
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    nodePort: 30705
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  - name: stat
    nodePort: 30711
    port: 1024
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1024
  selector:
    run: haproxy-ingress
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 1.2.3.4
```

Edit2:

For testing I am getting the service data manually.

```golang
data "kubernetes_service" "test" {
  metadata {
    name = "haproxy-ingress"
    namespace = "ingress"
  }
}

output "test_svc_state" {
    value = data.kubernetes_service.test.status
}
```

```sh
test_svc_state = tolist([
  {
    "load_balancer" = tolist([
      {
        "ingress" = tolist([
          {
            "hostname" = ""
            "ip" = "1.2.3.4"
          },
        ])
      },
    ])
  },
])
```

Comment: As shown in your last block, the spec.externalIPs is not set (tolist(null)), so your error seems to be normal. Note that when provisioning a LoadBalancer service, the endpoint addresses allocated to your by your IAAS would show in the status of your Service object: not the spec. Once you would have created that Service, wait for a few seconds and check back on your object: status should have been updated by your cloud controller.

Comment: as I mentioned, in my question. The service exists before running this apply here. In fact I can see the IP before I do this in the console. How can I get the status? Its not mentioned in the docs. But you are right, at the end I want to have a wait for, to wait for that IP. But I also dont find docs how to get that. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/manifest#using-wait_for-to-block-create-and-update-calls

Comment: Are you sure that IP you're seeing in the console isn't an address out of your Services status / can you share the YAML or JSON definition, including its status? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer . An externalIP implies your Kubernetes nodes would accept traffic for that IP address, whereas LoadBalancer Services implies the external IP address is held by another device which would redirect clients (with address translation).

Comment: what do you mean including its status? ![external ip](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/88435047/129325421-ae8782f2-aa52-40f1-b1f7-6a26ea42fb9f.png)

Comment: I can do this stuff by hand with kubectl or kustomize and az cli. So I kinda know its should work. I just struggle to get the allocated IP of the loadbalancer. Maybe I am posting the wrong things here but I think the question itself tells what I want. If you know the right command, please share.

Comment: Using kubectl, describe the service, as YAML or JSON, you should find a `.status`, after the `.spec` block.

Comment: I have updated my question there is no option to output this as yaml as far as I can see.

Comment: try with `k get -o yaml service/haproxy-ingress -n ingress`

Comment: ok did that.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Next, we need to figure out why it would not show in terraform: doc would suggest it should be there/usable: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/service . Any chance the ServiceAccount terraform uses doesn't have privileges to get `services/status` (different RBAC resource than `services`) ?

Comment: terraform is using my azure account while doing the things.  I have updated the question once more showing that I can fetch the service and also get that ip. At least its showing that actually that wait for example is correct keyword wise.  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/manifest#using-wait_for-to-block-create-and-update-calls

Comment: Status is just not listed here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/manifest#using-wait_for-to-block-create-and-update-calls I dont think it has to do with permission. It just not supossed to come with.